# how to toogle tex boolean inside lualatex code

Tags: luatex, tex-core

I have classical tex boolean:

```
\newif\ifprintanswers
\printanswersfalse
```

I also have luacode that can read some environment variable:

```
\begin{luacode}
     if os.getenv('C') == '1' then
         tex.print(\printanswerstrue)
     end
\end{luacode}
```

But I can't get the `\printanswerstrue` command to execute as expected (i.e. toggle the boolean state to true). Instead I always get a message stating "Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line xxx."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one reason I never use the luacode environments they are a group so it's as if you had `\begin{center}\printanswerstrue\end{center}`  so it goes false again at the end of the environment,

```
\directlua{%
if os.getenv('C') == '1' then
         tex.print("\string\\printanswerstrue")
     end
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on group. Didn't know that.

Comment: @BobMorane the luacode package saves you worrying about how many `\\ ` and `\string` you need, but swaps in other things to worry about, it's not a clear win:-)

Comment: BTW one can avoid needing the double backslash by quoting strings using `[[ … ]]` instead of `" … "` (so, `tex.print([[\string\printanswerstrue]]`), and avoid the `\string` too by putting `tex.print([[\printanswerstrue]])` in a file say `foo.lua` and doing `\directlua{'foo.lua'}`.