# LuaTeX : executing Tex Command within luacode environment

Tags: luatex

In my project I want to execute some LaTeX commands from inside a `luacode` environment. I have reproduced a dummy example in my MWE. In the code below, I don't understand why my function is executed when I use `\directlua` and not when I use the `luacode` environment (you can comment/uncomment in my MWE). I'd prefer using the `luacode` environment (or `luacode*`) because in my editor the words are highlighted contrary to `\directlua`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
  function setParindentToZero()
    tex.sprint('\\setlength{\\parindent}{0pt}')
  end
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\directlua{setParindentToZero()}

% \begin{luacode}
% setParindentToZero()
% \end{luacode}

test

\end{document}
```

EDIT :

Making the command global does work for the example above, but doesn't work for the example below :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{luacode}
  function setMargin()
    tex.sprint('\\global\\geometry{paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=10cm}')
    %tex.sprint('\\geometry{paperwidth=10cm,paperheight=10cm}')
  end
\end{luacode}

\directlua{setMargin()}

% \begin{luacode}
% setMargin()
% \end{luacode}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

Do some commands have restrictions and are not allowed to be global ?

Comment: you can not apply `\global` to arbitrary commands sometimes (like _spme_ uses of `\setlength` it may accidentally have the intended effect but only by luck and generally it will error or make the wrong thing global.

Comment: I think it's just much easier not to use `luacode` here the environments form a group so make all local assignments be discarded.

Comment: I agree it looks silly here, but in my project it does make sense. Anyway, I can use `\directlua` for my needs, but it still doesn't explain to me why `luacode` doesn't behave the same way.

Comment: `luacode` is a latex environment and _every_ latex environment works that way, try `\begin{center}\setlength\textwidth{2cm}\end{center}`  the setting is discarded.

Comment: "Do some commands have restrictions and are not allowed to be global ?" no latex command supports `\global`. It is a low level primitive that can be used with some primitive assignments but nothing that uses a format-defined syntax,

Comment: basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698937/1090